# What is wrong with my mySQL Trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to make a simple trigger that logs update events. However I get Error near " BEGIN ...". if I use single quotes, i.e. 'update_log' and 'customer', then the error is near ' 'update_log....'

```
use tal;
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER onUpdate
BEFORE UPDATE ON customer
BEGIN
INSERT INTO update_log VALUES(user(), 'An Udpdate operation against the customer table.', now());
END//
delimiter ;
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: Missing for each row

Comment: I want one log entry per update, not many in a loop...

Comment: Mihai is right: `CREATE TRIGGER onUpdate
BEFORE UPDATE ON customer FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN`

Comment: He doenst want to use for each row because he needs only 1 insert for each update sequence.Edit your question with the real problem,didnt downvote you.

Comment: Maybe use INSERT IGNORE and in the destination table put an unique index on all 3 rows.Mysql doenst accept lack of for each row

Comment: Mihai is right!  I was getting ahead of myself, we gotta check each row for an update. Only the row(s) updated will be found, one log entry per row updated. Combing a multi-row update to one log entry would require additional logic beyond the scope of a simple trigger. If you write it up as an answer @Mihai I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Oracle mysql needs  FOR EACH ROW

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER onUpdate
BEFORE UPDATE ON customer
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO update_log VALUES(user(), 'An Udpdate operation against the customer table.', now());
END//
delimiter ;
```